# Moving from hg to github

Tags: git, mercurial, move

I did my search and found this link helpful.

http://hivelogic.com/articles/converting-from-mercurial-to-git/

I followed everything and it works fine but how do I access my github now? where is the new repo location on github?

Comment: I just found out that I was using incorrect /path/to/repo. It should have been local (I just read the error message carefully!!!- so much for fast reading..). Path/to/repo is the location to your local repository on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that I was using incorrect /path/to/repo. It should have been local (I just read the error message carefully!!!- so much for fast reading..). Path/to/repo is the location to your local repository on your system. –